# How to override browser/sytem scaling from a webpage

Tags: html, css, nuxt.js

I'm working on nuxt universal website and it is working and displaying fine on all the major screen sizes, resolutions and devices except few laptops which has 125% scaling on by default.

I can make the website display correctly by disabling high-dpi settings of the browser or by disabling system scaling. But it needed to be done manually by the user.

My question is, is there any method to tell the browser to ignore or disable system scaling?

Comment: Might be this link help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Comment: Generally it's better to work on making the site's appearance responsive enough to look decent at any size, rather than locking the users into one specific size. However, depending on the device, this may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Why would you *want* to disable what users have explicitly set as what they consider best for them?  Good web pages never set font sizes in pixels; they always use relative (e.g. %) sizes and honour the default "em" size that the user has requested.

Comment: @GovindParashar Thank you for the info. It is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @DBS The site is responsive and works fine on all the sizes except the few, same model laptops which have 1920*1080 resolution on 15" screen and has 125% scaling set by windows. As far as I know, this is a known issue and almost every website I checked on those laptops looking a little bit weird when comparing to other devices.  
https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-google-chrome-scaling-on-win-10/

Comment: @RayButterworth The site is responsive, sizes are relative and used 'em' throughout the site. Actually, I don't want to **disable** anything, but trying to find a way to scale it back to the original ratio using CSS/JS.  Mainly the SVG elements are the one which suffers from the scaling issue. The site displaying fine without any issue if I set the windows scaling setting back to 100%

Comment: I think this is still a valid issue; I have similar requirements and it's related to wanting the scaling to be represented naturally regardless of the users screen dpi settings. this way 100px is still 100px regardless of the DPI/Scale setting.